# Do I need a transit visa for Canada if I have a Canadian Travel Document and am transiting from Canada?

Tags: transit, canada, yyz

I'm a protected person in Canada and I am traveling from there to Egypt for the summer. I will be departing from Ottawa and transiting through Toronto before heading to Egypt. I will be using my Canadian Travel Document to travel. Will I need a transit visa when I reach Toronto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You do not need a transit visa for a domestic flight.

Comment: Nor is there any situation where someone with a Canadian refugee travel document would ever need a Canadian transit visa.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any visa to enter Canada, because you have the Canadian travel document itself.

Further, you don't need any document to enter Canada because you are already in Canada.

And you don't need any sort of international travel documents for a purely domestic flight.

You do need the travel document to return to Canada after your trip to Egypt.

Comment: ... but will need some official provincial or federal government-issued picture id - such as driver’s licence, health card or passport - to board the Ottawa-Toronto flight.